# How to approximate detected edges to form a shape?

Tags: image-processing, object-detection

I am trying to extract the car from an image, removing the background.
I have detected the edges in the image using Canny Edge Detection.
How do I connect the edges to form an approximate enclosed box around the car ?

Sample Image after Edge Detection -

[image]

Comment: If you mean to identify the car from photos of cars after edge detection, you're probably looking at a neural network of some sort.  If the photos of cars may be shown in various angles, you'd have to likewise train the neural network to identify the car for each possible angle (flip the image and pass it through neural network to be able to identify symmetrical cars and halve the solution space).  The bounding box once you identify where the car is in the photo is trivial.

Comment: @Neil I dont want to predict if there is a car in the image or not. I know there is a car labelled with its position (front, rear, left side or right side view). What I am looking for is to extract the given car in the image.

Comment: If you wanted to find the bounds of a face in a photo, even if you *know* there is a face in that photo, you still have to *detect* the face using face detection algorithms in order to be able to find the bounds of the face.  Same is true for the car, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Neil I agree. If I train my neural network to find cars, do I really need to do edge detection then ? I think I can directly mask it, can't I ?